# Do I need to "commit" a .val() change in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've got a function which looks a bit like this:

```
$('#CompanyDropDown').bind("change", function () {
    $('#Products').find('.ProductDropDown').each(function () {
        setRates(this);
    });
    identifyLowestRate();
});
```

Basically we've got some product rows, and some columns for each product, one of which is "Rate". When the Company dropdown changes, all the products change, and the rate column is updated.

Say we need to find the lowest rate across all products, whenever the products get shuffled.

setRates is doing something like:

```
$('#Product1').val(foo);
```

identifyLowestRate is doing something like this (looping over Products):

```
lowestRate = Math.min(parseFloat(lowestRate), parseFloat($(this).val()));
```

`identifyLowestRate` looks again at the product loop and finds the lowest rate. However the problem is it's finding the previous lowest rate *as if the `setRates` is still not finished*. In fact if you set a breakpoint or an alert just prior to `identifyLowestRate` you can indeed see that the setRates changes haven't yet been committed to our webpage.

Is that a "thing" in jQuery - you have to commit the change in some way before you can retrieve a value from .val()?

Comment: Can you create a complete example and post a jsFiddle?

Comment: AWolff? posted a comment (since deleted) about checking whether setRates() was doing some async ajax ... which it is/was ... thanks AWolff if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

No you never have to commit a change to `val()`.  You may have to be careful about the order your code is being executed in though from your code snippets it appears fine.  But, if you call asynchronous functions then that likely is the source of your error.

Comment: yes, dropping `async: false` into the ajax in setRates has solved it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Passing a value to val() sets and "commits" it right away. Calling it again will retrieve the latest value for that input.

http://api.jquery.com/val/